# Annotating gene names or gene IDs to a dataframe containing SNPs?

Tags: r, gene, sequence-annotation, snp, filtering

I have a large data-frame (excel file) of SNPs with genotyping data. I need to filter the data to get SNP information of a specific gene alone. The list is too long to do it manually. I was wondering of annotating the SNPs with the gene names so that I can filter using the gene name. Does anyone know of a good R package to perform the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your SNP file contains genomic positions - please clarify if not. For example, you could have an rsID column, chromsome, and position column that contain "rs3088379", "chr1", "54225281".

**Approach #1:** use R, as you suggest.

`ensembldb` is an R package that may be what you're looking for: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ensembldb.html.

You could map the genomic positions of your SNPs to gene names by adapting their workflow: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ensembldb/inst/doc/coordinate-mapping.html.
After you've mapped the genomic position, you could filter for your gene name.

**Approach #2:** use bedtools.

You can convert your Excel file of genomic positions to a tab-delimited BED format. https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/overview.html has an overview. So, your first SNP would turn into

```
chr1 54225280 54225281 rs3088379
```

--> make sure you turn 1-based to 0-based coordinates!
You could then download the coordinates of your gene in BED format from your favorite source, like [UCSC Table Browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?command=start).

Then, you run `bedtools intersect` with your SNP BED and your gene BED. What remains is just that gene's SNPs.